# Can't locate scripts/Config.pm in @INC (you may need to install the scripts::Config module)

Tags: perl

```
Can't locate scripts/Config.pm in @INC
(you may need to install the scripts::Config module)
(@INC contains:
    /etc/perl
    /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.24.1
    /usr/local/share/perl/5.24.1
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.24
    /usr/share/perl5
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.24
    /usr/share/perl/5.24
    /usr/local/lib/site_perl
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base
) at scripts/Training.pl line 54.
```

(Line breaks added for readability)

I have tried to install the module with cpan install scripts::Config, but it doesn't work.

```
Loading internal null logger. Install Log::Log4perl for logging messages
Reading '/home/japangly/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Thu, 03 Jan 2019 13:29:03 GMT
Warning: Cannot install scripts::Config, don't know what it is.
Try the command
    i /scripts::Config/
to find objects with matching identifiers.
```

I tried to create links in /usr/local but it is empty:

```
ln -s /usr/{,local/}lib/perl5/5.8.3

ln -s /usr/{,local/}lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.3
```

https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=746288

I use google cloud platform:

$ which perl `/usr/bin/perl`

$ perl -e "print join(\"\n\", @INC);"

```
/etc/perl
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.24.1
/usr/local/share/perl/5.24.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.24
/usr/share/perl5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.24
/usr/share/perl/5.24
/usr/local/lib/site_perl
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base
```

Comment: `Can't locate scripts/Config.pm ... at scripts/Training.pl` - so please show us what `scripts/Training.pl` looks like. Maybe you are just missing the line `use lib '.', 'scripts';` in `Training.pl` or you are launching `Training.pl` from the wrong directory.

Comment: $| = 1;

if ( @ARGV < 1 ) {
   print "usage: Training.pl Config.pm\n";
   exit(0);
}

# load configuration variables
require( $ARGV[0] ); (line 54)

Comment: Ah - so your script expects to be run from the directory where `Config.pm` exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is:

> Can't locate scripts/Config.pm ... at scripts/Training.pl line 54

The lines 53 and 54 look like

```
#line 53
$| = 1; if ( @ARGV < 1 ) { print "usage: Training.pl Config.pm\n"; exit(0); } # load configuration variables
require( $ARGV[0] );
```

The script expects to be run from the directory where the file `Config.pm` exists. Maybe alternatively you can run it as `perl scripts/Training.pl scripts/Config.pm` or put `Config.pm` into the current directory instead of having it in `scripts/`.

You might want to add `.` to the module search path by adding the following line to `scripts/Training.pl`, to future-proof it when upgrading Perl from 5.24 to a newer version:

```
use lib '.';
```

Comment: Wow. It's so weird to look for modules relative to the current dir. I was just about to submit an edit that used `$RealBin` instead of `.`, but `.` is actually the "correct" hack here. (The correct fix would be to use `do './'.$path` instead of `do $path` to forgo using `@INC`. That still leaves the security hole of using code as data.)

Comment: @ikegami `$RealBin` is likely the preferrable approach, but I don't know the script and the environment things are run in, so `.` seems to be less invasive. Still ...